# Using response_with in Rails, how can I prevent execution of create action on not accepted MIME types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, mime-types, restful-architecture

I'm building a RESTful API using Rails 3.2.21. The API should only response to xml or json for now. I have a simple resource called Users with a create action, that creates a new user on a POST Request.

Here is the Code for doing that:

```
respond_to :json, :xml

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.save
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

Everything goes fine so far, but then I tried to check the error cases. So if I do a POST request to /users.html, the answer is '406 Not Acceptable'. What is correct. But then I saw in the database, that the user was created anyway. So the create action is executed although the requested accept format (html) is not supported and a 406 error is responded.

I don't know if this is intended. Until now I really liked response_with from Rails, because it does lots of stuff for me, but this behaviour seems to be odd. From the perspective of a client you try to create a new user, receive 406 and you obviously assume that the request failed, so the user is not created, right?

Since I've defined the accepted MIME types in the class method respond_to, it should be possible for Rails, to prevent execution of the entire action. Sure, respond_to is only related to the http response, but then for the client it is still unknown which part of the POST request succeeded and which failed.

Are there any setting or additional functions in Rails what I've overseen or is this just 'not thought to the end' in case of POST requests using respond_with or is this behaviour even intended to react like that? Of course I can add some custom before_filters for checking the MIME types, but then I can also remove respond_with and handle everything on my own.

I'm looking for a nice and clean solution for that problem using respond_with.

Comment: 406 is the error response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept-Type HTTP header in your  request.

Comment: The 406 errors response is expected, because of not supported Accept-Type: html. The problem is that in this case the create action is still executed successfully and actually not failing, since the user is created.